# How to sanitize and process raw HTML from a CMS in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt3

I have a Nuxt3 website connecting to a Strapi CMS. I get my content from the API in plain HTML.

In the Nuxt3 app I want to process that HTML

- Sanitize the HTML;
- Handle external URL's and add target="_blank" and rel="noopener" to them.

I tried using a function like this, but I think it won't work because it's SSR so you got no document.

```
const sanitizeAndAddAttributes = (html: any) => {
  const div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = html;

  // Get all anchor tags
  const links = div.querySelectorAll("a");

  links.forEach((link) => {
    const href = link.getAttribute("href");

    // Check if the link is external (http or https)
    if (href && (href.startsWith("http:") || href.startsWith("https:"))) {
      // Add target="_blank" and rel="nofollow" attributes
      link.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
      link.setAttribute("rel", "nofollow");
    }
  });

  // Return the updated HTML
  return div.innerHTML;
};
```

Comment: You should have some components from the CMS to display it in your frontend, no? Otherwise, check those answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+sanitize